# How to restore Xubuntu 14.04 Default Icons?

Tags: xubuntu, icons

Hey beloved community!

I really screwed up today, I was fooling around as root via terminal in the icons folder and I accidentally deleted all my icons. I was wondering, is it possible to reinstall the default Xubuntu 14.04 icons/themes? If yes, could anyone please share the terminal command for that? I googled my problem but couldn't find anything.. Gosh, lesson learned, never fool around while logged in as root!

I checked my trash bin, but unfortunately there's nothing in it.

Any information would be greatly appreciated!

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop
```

And see if that solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately there are still no icons :-( .

Comment: @LinuxDudester, I took a look at [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2073323&page=2) where it suggests deleting your ~/.config folder. Try this: `mv ~/.config ~/.config_old` then reboot and see if that solves the issue. If it doesn't, go ahead and reverse that command

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't work. I was asked to reboot. So I did, but after I log in there are still no icons, not even in  settings -> Appearance -> Icons , boy I really screwed up, I'm afraid I have to reinstall the whole system :-(

Comment: @LinuxDudester try these steps: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall tango-icon-theme tango-icon-theme-common`. It appears that these are the icons that xubuntu actively uses when it installs for the first time. Packages `xubuntu-icon-theme` and `xfdesktop4` look like promising candidates, as well.

Comment: Thanks musher, almost all icons are back, except for "about me", "menu editor" and "theme configuration" in the settings manager.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xfce4-settings xubuntu-default-settings xfce4-utils` WARNING: This will probably reset all your settings to how it was when you first installed xubuntu, so this may not be the ideal solution, and I'm not positive that it will solve it

Comment: Thanks, this didn't work for me either. So I just copied and pasted the icons from my Xubuntu install disk. That seems to be the easiest way so far. Thanks for your help though, it's much appreciated!